# How do I use phone to login to a tvOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, tvos

I have an app that uses the Parse server, and it runs on both iOS and tvOS. Currently, you login on the tvOS by simply typing in the username and password. I'd like to have some kind of method where it can use the existing log in on the iOS app in order to log in. Make things a bit simpler than typing in on the tv, and also making it easier if a user forgot their password. Is there a way to do this? I've been searching for a while and all that keeps popping up is tutorials for Multipeer Connectivity, which I don't think is what I need here.

Comment: iCloud password ?

Comment: @PtitXav No, just their account password for that specific app. Trying to do something like what Disney+ does where you could open the app on the phone, it would see the tv app, and allow you to login to the same account currently logged into on the phone, without having to type in the username and password.